# ECLIPSE - Lenovo A820 apk installation error

Tags: android, eclipse

I have problem when I want to run my project in Eclipse.

I get these errors:
**Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
Please check logcat output for more details.
Launch canceled!**

I try to run this project on LENOVO A820 with Android 4.1.2

When I just put compiled .apk file on my phone and install it via any Android File Manager everything works.

Could anyone tell me how to fix this problem in order to install projects directly via Eclipse ?

Comment: Can u post the Logcat error

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6xNbXHeXNOLZ2VpTmFONGpnNGM/

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall your application from the device first
2. Then try running it through Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

1. Try Installing missing drivers of your phone(if not installed)

2.Enabling this function is a piece of cake—simply go to Settings -> Security.-> Unknown Sources
[image]

3.Enable the function in Settings -> Developer Options -> USB debugging.

Hope it helps